# memory allocation of structure error in c (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, heap-memory

hello i am using c and i compile it by gcc in ubuntu but i have a strange error with memory allocation my code :

```
int INIT_NETWORK(int * layer_number,int layer_size){

int i,j,k;

//check if the data from user is valid
if(layer_size<=0)
    return -1;
for(i=0;i<layer_size;i++)
    if(layer_number[i]<=0)
        return -1;
layers_count=layer_size;
// allocate the layers structures
layer=(struct layers*) malloc(layer_size* sizeof(struct layers));
if(layer==NULL)
    return -1;
//allocate the neurals for the layers
for(i=0;i<layer_size;i++)
{
    layer[i].size=layer_number[i];
    layer[i].neural=(struct neurals *) malloc(sizeof(struct neurals)*layer_number[i]);
    if(layer[i].neural==NULL)
        return -1;
    if(i==layer_size-1)
        break;

    layer[i].weight=(struct matrix **) malloc(layer_number[i]*sizeof(struct matrix *));//allocate weight raw
    if(layer[i].weight==NULL)
        return -1;
    for(j=0;j<layer_number[i];j++)
    {
        layer[i].weight[j]=(struct matrix *) malloc(layer_number[i+1]*sizeof(struct matrix));//allocate weight column
        if(layer[i].weight[j]==NULL)
            return -1;
        for(k=0;k<layer_number[i+1];k++)//give the weights and the bais random values.
        {
            layer[i].weight[j][k].weightV=(double) 3/(rand()%20+1)-1.5;
        }
    }   
    layer[i].neural[j].bais=3/(rand()%20+1) -1.5;
}

for(j=0;j<layer_number[i];j++)
    layer[i].neural[j].bais=3/(rand()%20+1)-1.5;
output_val=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*layer[i].size);
if(output_val==NULL)
    return -1;
layer[i].weight=NULL;//the output layer doesn't have weights.
//we have a bug here by the pointer.
for(k=0;k<layers_count;k++){
    printf("on layer:%d\n",k);
    for(j=0;j<layer[k].size;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<layer[k+1].size;i++)
            printf("%lf\t",layer[1].weight[j][i].weightV);
        printf("|\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

and my structure and data that i use it:

```
//define the neurals structure
struct neurals{
    double x;//the input 
    double a;//the output
    double bais;
};
//define struct for both weight and deltaW
struct matrix{
    double weightV;
    double deltaW;
};

//define the layers structure
struct layers{
     struct neurals * neural;//pointer to array of neural for a single layer
     uint16 size;
     struct matrix ** weight;//the weight's matrix for this layer and the next one


};

struct layers * layer=0;
uint16 layers_count;
double * output_val=0;
```

and the problem was in the output:
on layer:0
-0.750000   -1.071429   -1.333333   -1.312500   |
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

but the strange thing that when i try can assign the values  to the data i can and i can print it directly . but when i exit the loops and try to print it or when i try to send my data to another function i can just calculate my first raw.

i am try to print the addresses that i allocate it and the result :

```
on layer:0
0x559bc6b43350  |
0xbff8000000000000  |
0x559bc6b433f0  |
on layer:1
0xbff8000000000000  |
0x559bc6b43540  |
0x559bc6b435a0  |
0x559bc6b43600  |
on layer:2
0x559bc6b43710  |
0xbff8000000000000  |
0x559bc6b43790  |
0x559bc6b437d0  |
0x559bc6b43810  |
on layer:3
0x559bc6b438c0  |
0x3ff8000000000000  |
0x559bc6b43900  |
```

why some of them have the same address ?

Comment: my data is int lay[5]={3,4,5,3,1}; for layer_number variable and the layer size is 5

Comment: `3/(rand()%20+1)` is integer division.  Maybe `3.0/(rand()%20+1)`?

Comment: for the variable weightV i correct it and put before (double) but for bais i don't  but i dount think that this make the error

Comment: The content of `layer[i].neural` is not assigned when `(i==layer_size-1)` is true.  Is it used in later `for(j=0;j<layer_number[i];j++)
    layer[i].neural[j]`?

Comment: no the weight not assigned because the i use the weight from layer to layer and layer_size-1 is the last layer so it useless

Comment: OK , so then nether is `layer[i].weight` assigned in `INIT_NETWORK()`.  It seems odd to, on the last loop iteration to allocate one pointer member `neural` (and not use it) but then not allocate nor assign member `layer[i].weight` leaving it in an unknown state.

Comment: i am allocating everything i need and the array layer is a global variable that i need to share it with all the program but i try to print the weight to deduce the error